# Change derailleur for new cassette?

Tags: derailleur, cassette

I currently run Shimano SG-B-53/39 chain rings coupled to a 9 speed 13/23 cluster. If I was to change my cassette to a 9 speed 11/32 would I need to also change my derailleur?

Comment: It depends on which derailleur you have now. Look up derailleur capacity.

Comment: If you need lower gears, you should also probably change out the crankset to a compact 50/34.  A 34-28 lowest gear is about the same as a 39-32, and you might not have to change your rear derailleur at all, depending on the exact model as most Shimano road rear derailleurs can handle a 28 without any problem. A 50-11 at 90 rpm gives you 31.6 mph - if you're strong enough to get there.  A 53-11 at 90 rpm only gets you up to 33.5 mph - and that 2 mph is really **hard** as power is proportional to speed **cubed**. And you wouldn't have the huge jumps that a 9-speed 11-32 cassette had.

Answer (score 2):

As ojs says in comments - depends on the derailleur, but it's very likely that you would have to swap the derailleur to accommodate an 11-32 cassette. Older 9 speed groupsets were not designed for wider range cassettes, they had small gaps between ratios instead. You may be able to get away with a 12-28 though.

The derailleur specs you need to find are: max rear sprocket size and total capacity. Total capacity must be equal to or larger than (largest sprocket teeth - smallest sprocket teeth) + (large ring teeth - small ring teeth).